# Some questions regarding recursion

Tags: java, recursion

What is direct recursions? What is infinite recursion?

What is a base case and why is it necessary/important?

example code:

```
public static void indifferent(int x, int y) {

    if (x <= y) {// base case
        System.out.print("!");
    }else {
        System.out.print(x);

        indifferent(x - 1, y + 2);

        System.out.print(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me explain infinite recursion. See first sentence.

Comment: Let's add an example with a **base case**; shampoo instructions read; *lather*, *rinse*, *repeat* (**as necessary**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Direct recursion is when a method calls itself (as in your example code). Indirect recursion is when method `a()` calls method `b()`, which itself (either directly or indirectly) calls method `a()` again.
2. Infinite recursion is recursion that never ends. Another way of putting it is that infinite recursion is when the base case either does not exist or is never encountered.
3. A base case is a set of argument values that causes the method to return without a recursive call (either direct or indirect).

Answer (score 2):

Direct recursion: Method invokes itself.

Indirect recursion: Method invokes some other method and after many invocations, the call returns, to a situation where the first calling method is invoked again.

Base case: It is an important component of any recursion function. It is a condition for recursive method to stop calling itself and thus end the recursion i.e. stop going deeper in recursion. Basically, if you think of recursion as a yoyo then it is the base case when the recursion is at its extreme end.

infinite recursion: It is a recursion which never ends. Basically it is a recursive function which does not have a base case. (a yo-yo which doesn't come back and goes all over the place.)

Checkout these interesting recursion images at this [link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-photo-that-explains-recursion)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algorithm for climbing stairs

```
climb:
    if you are at the top
        stop
    otherwise 
        step up and then climb
```

That shows you direct recursion (climb is a step inside climb) and base case (stop if you are at the top).

Two cases of infinite recursion:

```
climb:
    step up and then climb

climb:
    if you are at the top
        stop
    otherwise 
        step up and then step down and then climb
```

The first has no base case and the second will never reach the base case:

Finally, indirect recursion:

```
group climb:
    if there's no one in the group
        stop
    otherwise
        step up

step up:
    if first in group is at top
        remove them from the group then group climb
    otherwise
        step up first in group then group climb
```